# Cannot import cjs component into a next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a design system. So far, I only created a single component:

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import "../app/globals.scss";

export default function Header() {
  return <h1 className="text-red-600">Header</h1>;
}
```

it is exported by two other files:

```
// src/components/index.ts
"use client";

import Button from "./button/button";
import Header from "./header";

export { Button, Header };
```

and

```
// src/index.ts
"use client";

import "./app/globals.scss";

export * from "./components";
```

I'm then using rollup to bundle my components, using this config:

*rollup config*

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import { dts } from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

const config = [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.build.json" }),
      // commonjs(),
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: "./postcss.config.mjs",
        },
        minimize: true,
        extract: true,
        inject: true,
        plugins: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.ts"), autoprefixer()],
      }),
      peerDepsExternal(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/src/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],

    // ignore css and scss when generating types
    external: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/],
  },
];

export default config;
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "@hello/ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "my UI Library",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20",
    "npm": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "build-lib": "rollup -c rollup.config.js --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "check:component-update": "npx shadcn-ui diff",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "dev-lib": "rollup -c rollup.config.js --bundleConfigAsCjs --watch",
    "lint:css": "npx stylelint ./src/**/*.{css,scss}",
    "lint:js": "next lint",
    "lint:ts": "npx tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "concurrently npm:lint:*",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "start": "next start",
    "storybook:build": "storybook build",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-accessible-icon": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "lucide-react": "^0.279.0",
    "next": "^13.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     ... my packages (removed for the sake of post length)
  }
}
```

And finally, *tsconfig.build.json*

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  }
}
```

This properly generates two new directories: `dist/cjs` and `dist/esm`

Now, when I try to import these components from another app, I get an error message:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined

Now, depending on how I import, I manage to fix the error:

```
import { Header } from "hello/ui" // this fails
import { Header } from "hello/ui/dist/esm" // this works
```

I'm faily new to bundling, and I have no clue whether this comes from rollup, from enxt, or from a faulty config. Any help would be greatly appreciated !